Are the bit masks in DataOutputStream necessary?
Java's DataOutputStream uses bit masks in its method implementations, such as in writeShort:
    public final void writeShort(int v) throws IOException {
        out.write((v >>> 8) & 0xFF);
        out.write((v >>> 0) & 0xFF);
        incCount(2);
    }

But I'm confused as to why. I understand & 0xFF masks off the 24 high-order bits, but doesn't OutputStream#write(int)'s contract say that it does that anyway? Its documentation says

The byte to be written is the eight low-order bits of the argument b. The 24 high-order bits of b are ignored.

So, couldn't writeShort just be written as follows?
    public final void writeShort(int v) throws IOException {
        out.write(v >>> 8);
        out.write(v >>> 0);
        incCount(2);
    }


maybe it is (was) just for security: to avoid errors since OutputStream#write takes an int and user can also (incorrectly) implement OutputStream

Note that the code looks different since Java 17 (https://github.com/openjdk/jdk17u/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/io/DataOutputStream.java#L171):
    public final void writeShort(int v) throws IOException {
        writeBuffer[0] = (byte)(v >>> 8);
        writeBuffer[1] = (byte)(v >>> 0);
        out.write(writeBuffer, 0, 2);
        incCount(2);
    }

That utilizes the byte[] writeBuffer (which previously only was used when writing long values).
The reason for this change is mentioned in two issue tickets:

JDK-8254078: DataOutputStream is very slow post-disabling of Biased Locking
JDK-8260273: DataOutputStream writeChars optimization

So, no, these casts have never been necessary but have been replaced by better code anyway.

Sure. That masking probably shouldn't have been done. But now, it shouldn't be reversed:

The gain is nothing. The masking doesn't add measurable cost to this operation.
The loss is nearly nothing. An implementation of an underlying outputstream could be bugged in this way (that it does not ignore the top 24 bits); it would be a bug that is hard to find and somewhat unlikely to have tests (that's sort of the point: The author of that impl forgot about it. If they forget about it when writing the implementation, they'd also forget about it when writing tests. Or, vice versa with TDD, they'd forget about it when writing the tests, and are unlikely to suddenly remember when writing the implementation). It's unlikely to come up (not much code that uses of OutputStream out in the wild relies on that 'top 24 bits are ignored' part of the spec). If it is, then code that worked fine before now fails for very hard to find reasons (the failure is: DataOutputStream no longer masks and the underlying outputstream is bugged in that it fails to ignore the top 24 bits).

So, weigh 'no gain' against 'virtually no loss' and the answer is clear enough: Don't change it.
